# Python: how to use a returned Dataframe from a function in another function

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am trying to figure out how to use a returned Dataframe from a function in another function. This is my current code:

```
# Top n countries having lowest confirmed cases

def lowest_eu_latest_update(n):
    n = int(n)
    return eu_daily_df.groupby('Country').sum().sort_values('Confirmed', ascending =False).reset_index().head(n).style.apply(highlight_col, axis=None)

l_sorted_eu_daily_df = eu_daily_df.groupby('Country').sum().sort_values('Confirmed', ascending =False).reset_index()

# Visualize
def bubble_chart(n):
    fig = px.scatter(l_sorted_eu_daily_df.head(n), x= "Country", y="Confirmed", size="Confirmed", color="Country",
               hover_name="Country", size_max=60)
    fig.update_layout(
    title = "Top " + str(n) + " Countries having lowest confirmed cases",
    xaxis_title = "Countries",
    yaxis_title= "Confirmed Cases",
    width = 900
    )
    fig.show()

# interact    
interact(lowest_eu_latest_update, n='10')    
interact(bubble_chart, n=10)
```

I rewrote the code like this:

```
def lowest_eu_latest_update(n):
    n = int(n)
    l_sorted_eu_daily_df = eu_daily_df.groupby('Country').sum().nsmallest(n, 'Confirmed').reset_index().style.apply(highlight_col, axis=None)
    return l_sorted_eu_daily_df

# Visualize
def bubble_chart(n):
    fig = px.scatter(l_sorted_eu_daily_df.head(n), x= "Country", y="Confirmed", size="Confirmed", color="Country",
               hover_name="Country", size_max=60)
    fig.update_layout(
    title = "Top " + str(n) + " Countries having lowest confirmed cases",
    xaxis_title = "Countries",
    yaxis_title= "Confirmed Cases",
    width = 900
    )
    fig.show()

# interact    
interact(lowest_eu_latest_update, n='10')    
interact(bubble_chart, n=10)
```

I know that `l_sorted_eu_daily_df` is a local variable, I tried `global l_sorted_eu_daily_df` but it didn't work.

Also, are there any way that I can slice DataFrame into a Sub-DataFrame based on condition. For example, DataFrame and I want to return a Sub-DataFrame based on condition `Country == 'United Kingdom'` and a Sub-DataFrame can be used in another function. 
[image]

Please let me know if I have too many question. Any though would be appreciated.

Comment: These are all very basic questions. Please look around for "Python use returned value" or "filter data Pandas". Try to be more specific.

Comment: Hi @Joe, I am sorry if my questions are confusing. So, my first question was: let have Def that return l_sorted_eu_daily_df so it can be used in another Def as now it is local variable. My 2nd question was that I want to have Def that slice a big DataFrame in to a Sub-Dataframe based on input condition, in this case is country name. and then use it in another Def. I hope now it would be more specific.

Comment: in `bubble_chart(n)` you need to call the function and assign the value from the function call like `my_data = l_sorted_eu_daily_df(50).head(4)`. Or give the parameter `n` in `px.scatter(l_sorted_eu_daily_df(50).head(n)`. This will call the function and insert the returned value "in-place".

Comment: I guess you are not passing the parameter `n` when you are calling the function